# how do I make two phpmailer contact forms work on the same page

Tags: php, jquery

using code from  here
https://www.codingsnow.com/2021/01/create-php-send-email-contact-form.html

```
    <h4 class="sent-notification"></h4>

    <form id="myForm">
        <h2>Send an Email</h2>

        <label>Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
        <br><br>

        <label>Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email">
        <br><br>

        <label>Subject</label>
        <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder=" Enter Subject">
        <br><br>

        <p>Message</p>
        <textarea id="body" rows="5" placeholder="Type Message"></textarea><!--textarea tag should be closed (In this coding UI textarea close tag cannot be used)-->
        <br><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="sendEmail()" value="Send An Email">Submit</button>
    </form>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendEmail() {
        var name = $("#name");
        var email = $("#email");
        var subject = $("#subject");
        var body = $("#body");

        if (isNotEmpty(name) && isNotEmpty(email) && isNotEmpty(subject) && isNotEmpty(body)) {
            $.ajax({
               url: 'sendEmail.php',
               method: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: {
                   name: name.val(),
                   email: email.val(),
                   subject: subject.val(),
                   body: body.val()
               }, success: function (response) {
                    $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                    $('.sent-notification').text("Message Sent Successfully.");
               }
            });
        }
    }

    function isNotEmpty(caller) {
        if (caller.val() == "") {
            caller.css('border', '1px solid red');
            return false;
        } else
            caller.css('border', '');

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

what do i need to change in both the files for it to work
right now when i put two contact forms on one page, both top working even though individually both of them are working..I have tried changes variable names and function names but cant figure out the error. in the network tab it says "failed, something went wrong"

Comment: Hard-coding parameters in function body kind of defeats the purpose of using functions. You need to provide variable information as function argument. Also, using IDs for everything tends to make things more difficult.

Comment: I only see one form? Can you update your code and show what you actually use?

Comment: It's also hard to see what the actual issue is. Where does the error _"failed, something went wrong"_ come from? Is it returned in your PHP (which you also should include in your question) or are you talking about some server error? The question is too vague and are missing crucial information/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll explain it with an example. Let's say you have a function to add up two numbers:

```
function add() {
    return 3 + 5;
}
```

If you ever need to add a different set of numbers, this function is useless. However, if you pass variable information as function argument you have a multiple purpose function:

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

As about assigning IDs in HTML, it adds more burden than benefits. Compare these two snippets and figure out which one is easier to use and extend:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#input1, #input2, #input3").each(function (index, input) {
      console.log(input.value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="input1" value="One">
  <input id="input2" value="Two">
  <input id="input3" value="Three">
</form>
```

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("input").each(function (index, input) {
      console.log(input.value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input value="One">
  <input value="Two">
  <input value="Three">
</form>
```

This is just an example to illustrate the point. The usual way to handle a form element is to assign it a name rather than an ID.